# What could prevent players from leaving an island?

Tags: dnd-5e, world-building

I am currently building a campaign for DnD.

The main plot plays out on an island the heroes are stranded after their ship goes off course and sinks.

They discover that this island is ruled by monsters that serve a mighty demon/ancient evil. There are no humans beside a small town/city that is regularly visited by the demons to take a few of the people living there to perform a ritual, sacrifice those people, feed on them, etc.

The main goal for the group is to defeat the evil force and free those humans.

The island is undiscovered because it is so far from the other continents.

#### My problem to solve

How do I stop my characters from just turning around and leaving the island in a self built ship/raft?

My first idea was to make it geographically difficult/impossible to leave by surrounding this island by a nearly closed ring of mountains (kinda in a U shape). An explanation for this could be that the island used to be a volcano that exploded (a real thing) and the mountain ring is what is left of the volcano.

My problem with this idea: is it believable?  Isn't it a bit too random for them to have been stranded exactly through the passage that is open?

Comment: And also what prevents the towns people from leaving?

Comment: What level are you adventurers, and at what level do you expect tham to overcome the evil ones?

Comment: Hi Nautha, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help). Unfortunately, this question seems to be more about asking for ideas, and the stack exchange format doesn't really handle ideas generation question very well. You might find that this question would suit a forum better, so [here's a list of forums we've come up with for such questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/35259). But if you have other questions that would suit RPG.SE, please feel free to ask!

Comment: @NathanS I sadly see now way I could edit the question to make it less opinion based. I have a bunch of ideas but even if I were to edit the post giving all of those ideas it wount change that it is opinion based.

Comment: Now that you have enough rep, please join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=rpg.stackexchange.com).  We can brain storm with you there.

Comment: This *is*, however, the sort of question Worldbuilding.SE has seemed to have luck fielding. It might be worth pinging someone in their main chat room (the Factory Floor, I think they call it?) to ask whether, if posted there, it'd likely be well-received.